# aws - my lambda isn't listed in the dropdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lex

This is while I'm developing a Lex function but I have had this issue with other services too.

I have a dropdown to select the lambda function but there are no functions available to select in the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is frequently due to being in the wrong region.**

Lambda may not be available (or that specific function is not created) in the same region as the functionality of the service (Lex in this case).

Solution:
For the lambda function, switch to the same region (N.Virginia in my case), create the function there and then it will appear in the dropdown.